# Android ListView with every item of xml file

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm trying to develop a messenger app for android. I will have an xml file with all the friends in, for example `<item>Peter L.</item>`. In the main activity, I want to show a ListView which contains all friends. How can I do this? And is it hard to include other informations such as the picture of the person or the last message (as in WhatsApp)?

Sorry for my english and the quite nooby questions :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your list view and its custom list adapter. Like described in below links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html